# Android - How to show Facebook and Twitter's login screen using Intent?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, android-intent, authentication

I have a screen with 2 buttons, one for Twitter and one for Facebook.

All I want to do is to redirect the user to the login/logout screen (on their respective apps) of Facebook/Twitter when the user hits its respective button.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

to open any url using your app use it

```
    Intent httpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
httpIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://m.facebook.com/"));                startActivity(httpIntent);
```

and do same for the teitteer just replace the url 
use the following link for demonstrations http://grabcodes.blogspot.com